# How to read a json file and return as dictionary in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

Trying to read a json file and return as dictionary:

```
  def js_r(filename):
  with open('num.json', 'r')as f_in:
  json_d = f_read()
```

How to return the dict function?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `json` module to decode it.

```
import json

def js_r(filename: str):
    with open(filename) as f_in:
        return json.load(f_in)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_data = js_r('num.json')
    print(my_data)
```

Comment: Did you call the function? i've updated the example.

Comment: Thanks :), i noticed some typo on myside .. Its working now

Comment: But it returns the object like a list, not as dict, how can it be transformed?