# Using Python Click to read a JSON file

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am new to python and I am trying to read in a JSON file, that for now I can just write out to a new file without any changes. I have been attempting to use the python package Click to do this but keep running into errors.

I'm sure this is relatively basic but any help would be appreciated. The latest version of the code I've tried is below.

```
 import json
 import os
 import click


 def dazprops():
     """Read Daz3D property File"""
     path = click.prompt('Please specify a location for the Daz3D Properties File')
     path = os.path.realpath(path)
     #dir_name = os.path.dirname(path)
     print(path)
     dazpropsf = open('path')
     print(dazpropsf)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     dazprops()
```

Comment: How is `click` relevant to any of this? Jusa accept a file name as the first command-line argument instead. You are attempting to open a file with the literal name `path` rather than the string in the variable by that name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476636/how-to-read-a-json-file-and-return-as-dictionary-in-python

Comment: I eventually have 5 files to load and output so using click will allow me to add a bit more functionality and look more presentable. Apologies if the question seems silly, this is for college and i'm relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could give you an idea how to achieve that using `click`:

```py
import click

def read_file(fin):
    content = None
    with open(fin, "r") as f_in:
        content = f_in.read()
    return content

def write_file(fout, content):
    try:
        print("Writing file...")
        with open(fout, "w") as f_out:
            f_out.write(content)
        print(f"File created: {fout}")
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"Couldn't write a file at {fout}. Error: {e}")

@click.command()
@click.argument('fin', type=click.Path(exists=True))
@click.argument('fout', type=click.Path())
def init(fin, fout):
    """
    FINT is an input filepath
    
    FOUT is an output filepath
    """
    content = read_file(fin)
    if content:
        write_file(fout, content)
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```